# Joda-Time remaining seconds?

Tags: java, jodatime

This has me completely stumped, as I am new to using the Joda API. How can I print out the remaining seconds?

```
DateTime time1 = DateTime.parse(c.lastBankTime);
DateTime time2 = new DateTime();
Seconds Interval = Seconds.secondsBetween(time1, time2);
Seconds minInterval = Seconds.seconds(10);

if(Interval.isGreaterThan(minInterval)){
    c.sendMessage("been 10 secs");
    c.lastBankTime = new DateTime().toString();
} else{
    c.sendMessage("Please wait n seconds"); //How do I get remaining seconds?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'remaining seconds', but is this what you are looking for?

```
 minInterval.minus(Interval).getSeconds()
```